# Why is this container missing one file in its volume mount?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-volume

Title is the question.

I'm hosting many docker containers on a rather large linux ec2 instance. One container in particular needs access to a file that gets transferred to the host before run time. The file in question is copied from a windows file server to the ec2 instance using control-m.

When the container image runs, we give it -v to specify a volume mount with a path on the host to that transferred file.

The file is not found in the container. If I make a new file in the container, the new file appears on the host. When I make a file on the host, it appears in the container. When I make a copy of the transferred file using `cp -p` the copied file DOES show up in the container, but the original still does not.

I don't understand why this is? My suspicion is something to do with it being on a windows server before control-m copies it to the ec2 instance.

**Details:**

The file lives in the path `/folder_path/project_name/resources/file.txt`
Its permissions are `-rwxrwxr-x 1 pyadmin pyadmin` where `pyadmin` maps to the containers root user.

It's approximately 38mb in size and when I run `file file.txt` I get the output `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`.

The repo also has a resources folder with files already in it when it is cloned, but none of their names conflict.

Docker Version: 20.10.13

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.11-buster
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
WORKDIR /folder_path/project_name

RUN apt-get auto-clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip poetry

COPY . .
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip poetry && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry install

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
```

Command to start container:

```
docker run --pull always --rm \
-v /folder_path/project_name/logs:/folder_path/project_name/logs \
-v /folder_path/project_name/extracts:/folder_path/project_name/extracts \
-v /folder_path/project_name/input:/folder_path/project_name/input \
-v /folder_path/project_name/output:/folder_path/project_name/output \
-v /folder_path/project_name/resources:/folder_path/project_name/resources \
my-registry.com/folder_path/project_name:image_tag
```

Comment: How can you tell the file isn't there?  If you, say, `docker run ... project_name:image_tag -e 'import os; print(os.listdir('/folder_path/project_name/resources'))'` (with the same `-v` options and image name) do you see it?

Comment: Is your host running SE Linux? This may prevent the docker container process to see the file in the filesystem. https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/what-is-selinux-and-how-its-selinux-used-in-docker/

Comment: It's an amazon linux ami. The file was being copied to the linux instance from a windows file system via an orchestration tool called control-m. When we `cp` the file to another file with a different name, the new file was mounted and visible. The only thing i can think is that there were BOM carried over that made it unable to be mounted and the `cp` command ignored those BOM when creating a copy.